# Getting extra character when copy string to iTerm

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, iterm, copy-paste

I'm using iTerm and when when pasting some string I've just copied from the terminal command prompt, I get some extra characters on prefix and suffix that match `00~` and `01~` respectively.

I.e.

I've copied the string:

```
./Build/Products/Debug/data.json
```

and it pasted the following output (same results when paste back in iTerm or in any other application):

```
00~./Build/Products/Debug/data.json01~
```

any idea who to avoid this?

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of ["When pasting in Terminal.app, `00~` is pasted at the start and `01~` at the end"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446859/when-pasting-in-terminal-app-00-is-pasted-at-the-start-and-01-at-the-end/446877#446877) (only difference is iTerm vs Terminal.app).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by invoking the **Reset** (either via menu or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). More options are listed in this [similar Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44848979/getting-strange-characters-when-pasting-into-my-iterm2-terminal)